# pointer to pointer problem

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I was studying trees and everything seem fine until i started a avl tree, which requires rotation. I built a rotation algorithm that works fine until the 2 or 3 rotation, the algorithm it's the following:

```
static void _nodeRotateRight(avl_tree* t, avl_tree_node** n) {
avl_tree_node* node = (*n)->left;

// refresh parents before rotate
if (node->right)
    node->right->parent = (*n);

if ((*n) == t->top) {
    t->top = node;
    node->parent = NULL;
}
else {
    (*n)->parent->right = node;
    node->parent = (*n)->parent;
}

(*n)->parent = (*n)->left;

// rotate nodes (pointers)
(*n)->left = node->right;
node->right = (*n);
(*n) = node;

// refresh heights
(*n)->right->height -= 2;
```

}

the error is on:
(*n)->parent->right = node;

actually works, but on the 3º rotation has a strange behaviour, assigning a new value to "right" actually changes (*_n) instead of right itself.
Obviously that (*_n)->parent->right points to (*_n), but if i assign a new value to right, i can't change (*_n) because they are different pointers with different addresses...
Any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Leave identifiers starting with an underscore to your compiler/library implementation.

Comment: @Anna - No, it isn't.

@pau.estelella - i tried that already... actually i had a problem some days ago because of that, it was driving me crazy until someone told me that, and it just solved everything, but not this case...

Comment: *n is almost certainly an alias for (*n)->parent->right.  Assigning that right pointer changes the value of *n.  But not the value of n.  Copy the value of *n into a local variable first.

Answer (score 1):

You should cache the value of of `*n`.

```
avl_tree_node *n1 = *n;
```

Now, regardless of how you change `*n`, `n1` will continue pointing to the original node.